# Changing background and text color for AppCompat Light DarlActionBar theme on android

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I have used AppCompat Light DarlActionBar theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

 </style>
```

How can I change the ActionBar background color and Text ActionBar text color ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the ActionBar color you can use the `color primary` for coloring the actionbar.

`<!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_color</item>`

and `textColorPrimary` for the color of your text anywhere in your application

`<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/OTDBackgroundTextColor</item>`

Comment: @color means I need to create a color.xml file too ?

Comment: @Gissipi_453 depends all on you, you can directly add a color there like `#fffff` or create a color.xml where you specify the color to have more control.

Answer (score -1):

This is an example code :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#C1000E</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>




<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.StatusBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#E5ED0E</item>
</style>
```

For more info check [android site](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) they are explaining everything

Comment: Note: this does not work for AppCompat v21 or higher, styling is now done through the material color palette as per the [release blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)